# Let Textmate "remember" the root password

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, textmate

There are times I need to edit root protected files, so I have to keep entering the root password again and again. I've already set up the rule so terminal is gonna ask me for root password only once per hour. Confirmed that is working. But I still have to enter the same password for textmate. Is there a way to get this resolved?

I understand the risk, but keep entering the same password is also too annoying.

Comment: As an aside: any details on *the rule so terminal is gonna ask me for root password only once per hour*?

Comment: Did you try `sudo mate filename`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called [`cocoasudo`](http://www.performantdesign.com/2009/10/26/cocoasudo-a-graphical-cocoa-based-alternative-to-sudo/) which is similar to `gksudo` for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making TextMate owned by root and set the setuid flag on it. Package these changes up as a toggling shell script if you don't want to leave it on indefinitely.